# "assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, gcc-warning

I'm fairly new to C and trying to write a function that inserts a node at the beginning of the list, using these two structs:

```
typedef struct singly_linked_list_node {
    char *data; 
    struct singly_linked_list_node *next;
} node;

typedef struct singly_linked_list_head {
    struct node *first;
    struct node *last;
    int size;
} sin_list;
```

My function is

```
void insert_at_start(sin_list* list, char *str)
{
    int length;
    node *newnode;
    newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    length = strlen(str) + 1;
    newnode->data = malloc(sizeof(length));
    strcpy(newnode->data, str);
    newnode->next = list->first;
    list->first = newnode;
    if (list->last == NULL) list->last = newnode;
}
```

When I compile I get the warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]" for the last 3 lines so obviously there's something I'm missing.

Comment: The type of **node** and **list** do not match

Comment: BTW  `newnode->data = malloc(sizeof(length));` --> `newnode->data = malloc(length);`

Comment: Why do you need **struct singly_linked_list_head**

Comment: `struct node *first; struct node *last;` --> `node *first; node *last;`

Comment: @user7  I need a pointer for the first node of the list, one for the last node and an int size in order to print the number of "items"/nodes in the list

Comment: **node and list do not have the same types**

Comment: There is at least one — probably several — other questions in C where there is a mismatch between `typedef struct X Y;` and later `struct Y *yp` and a type mismatch in the pointer types `Y *` and `struct Y *`.

Answer (score 1):

With the definition of `struct singly_linked_list_head` you use two implicit forward declarations to `struct` types. These are

```
struct node *first;
struct node *last;
```

Further you have a typedef for the `node`. The type `struct node` is never resolved, but it's okay for the compiler as long as you use only a pointer to it. In the language `C` there are two distinct name spaces for struct names and typedefs.

Fix your code by *using* your typedef:

```
typedef struct singly_linked_list_head {
    node *first;
    node *last;
    int size;
} sin_list;
```

*EDIT* When you allocate the Memory you should use the length of `str` and not the size of the variable `length` to allocate the Memory for `data`:

```
length = strlen(str) + 1;
newnode->data = malloc(sizeof(length));
```

Change to:

```
length = strlen(str) + 1;
newnode->data = malloc(length);
```